# Rails 4.2 engine reference column migration fails PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In an [Engine I have built](https://github.com/kickinespresso/book_store), I have 3 classes: books, categories and authors. The migrations for each of the classes is below. There is a 1 to many relationship between authors and books and between categories and books. The engine namespaces each of the classes to `book_store`. When using the same migrations on Postgresql (instead of sqlite) I get an error that one of the classes does not exist `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "authors" does not exist`

I'm not sure why this error is occurring. Should the namespace be in the reference as well? e.g, from this:

```
  t.references :author, index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.references :category, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

to this:

```
  t.references :book_store_author, index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.references :book_store_category, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

This seems like it would not work because then there would be an attribute in `BookStore::Books` named `book_store_author` and `book_store_category` resulting in `BookStore::Books.book_store_author` which would be not scoped to the engine properly.

Is it possible that I need to change my migration code to reflect the namespace of the engine on a separate line?

### Original code

## Authors

```
# This migration comes from book_store (originally 20150814153615)
class CreateBookStoreAuthors < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :book_store_authors do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.string :slug

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :book_store_authors, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

## categories

```
# This migration comes from book_store (originally 20150814153710)
class CreateBookStoreCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :book_store_categories do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :slug

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :book_store_categories, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

## books

```
# This migration comes from book_store (originally 20150814153733)
class CreateBookStoreBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :book_store_books do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :lead
      t.text :excerpt
      t.text :description
      t.decimal :price
      t.integer :cover_type
      t.integer :num_pages
      t.string :isbn
      t.integer :year
      t.string :buy_link
      t.string :size
      t.string :cover_image
      t.string :slug
      t.references :author, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :category, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :book_store_books, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

## Error:

```
/home/deploy/apps/saturnalia_books/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:797:in `migrate'
/home/deploy/apps/saturnalia_books/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/home/deploy/apps/saturnalia_books/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "authors" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "book_store_books" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_52f80cb3c5"
FOREIGN KEY ("author_id")
  REFERENCES "authors" ("id")
/home/deploy/apps/saturnalia_books/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/home/deploy/apps/saturnalia_books/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'


   ...

  PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "authors" does not exist
```

## edit

[here is the full stack trace](https://gist.github.com/cdesch/e0b6dc757cc56135427e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing model and migration files as below.

I have `blog` model which has many `tags` through `tagging` model.

So I updated `tagging` model to look like this

> ```
> module Blog
>     class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
>       belongs_to :tag, :class_name => "Blog::Tag"
>       belongs_to :post, :class_name => "Blog::Post"
>    end
>  end
> ```

And I modified `post` model like this.

> ```
> module Blog
>   class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
>     has_many :taggings, :class_name => "Blog::Tagging"
>     has_many :tags, through: :taggings
>   end
>  end
> ```

Migration file is modified as below

> ```
> class CreateBlogTaggings < ActiveRecord::Migration
>  def change
>    create_table :blog_taggings do |t|
>     t.integer :tag_id, index: true, foreign_key: true
>     t.integer :post_id, index: true, foreign_key: true
>  end
> end
> ```

So in your case change `t.references :author` to `t.integer :author _id` and `t.references :category` to `t.integer :category_id`.

This should resolve your migration issue.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Not sure why `t.references`/`t.belongs_to` wouldn't work...  I didn't need the `class_name: "Namespace::Class"`, but I am using isolate_namespace, so maybe that's why?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `PG::UndefinedTable`, so that table `author` that you are trying to reference can't be found my psql. And it couldn't be found because table is named `book_store_authors` here `create_table :book_store_authors`. 
I'm not sure why it was working on sqlite, but you certainly need to pass a full and valid table name as you were creating model (I mean in singular form if it is User or in plural if you in some reason was creating Users model) to `t.belongs_to` and `t.references`

Answer (score 0):

This is Indeed due to PostgreSql not understanding how to make the bridge between tables when not namespaced

You can fix that by just changing your migration files.

In your Book migration file:

change

```
t.references :author, index: true, foreign_key: true
t.references :category, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

with

```
t.references :author
t.references :category
```

then after your line

```
add_index :book_store_books, :slug, unique: true
```

add this

```
add_index(:book_store_books, 'author_id', :name => 'index_books_on_author')
add_index(:book_store_books, 'category_id', :name => 'index_books_on_category')
```

those lines manually create index to the table book_store_books

more informations here : http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index

foreign_keys are not required but you can still add them with the same method

With that, you don't have to change anything in your application and postgresql know how to manage references between namespaced tables

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with foreign_key, the rails api for adding foreign key use table name instead of model name. If you write a compounded line like this:
`t.references :author, index: true, foreign_key: true`

it will generate 2 separate commands: 

`add_column :book_store_books, :author_id, index: true
add_foreign_key :book_store_books, :authors`

the second command will cause `undefined relation "authors"`

Can fix by use 2 separate commands like this:

`t.references :author, index: true` and `add_foreign_key :book_store_books, book_store_authors`

So your migration file you be:

```
class CreateBookStoreBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :book_store_books do |t|
      # more lines go here
      # ...
      # bonus: you can define you slug unique index inline
      t.string :slug, index: true, unique: true
      t.references :author, index: true
      t.references :category, index: true
    end
    add_foreign_key :book_store_books, book_store_authors, column: :author_id
    add_foreign_key :book_store_books, book_store_categories, column: :category_id
  end
end
```